# how does an SSL certificate chain bundle arranged?

Tags: ssl, https, devops, tls1.2

I have 4 certificate files like this:

```
1.certum_certificate.crt
2.certum_certificate.pem
3.Intermediate_CA2.cer
4.Intermediate_CA.cer
5.Root_CA.cer
```

I put these files content by this order in a bundle file and i figured out that my SSL chain is incomplete.
how should i arrange them in bundle file?

Comment: The PEM is not part of the certificate chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just concatenate the three parts into a single file like this (`fullchain.pem`) :

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFKTCCBBGgAwIBAgISA/UUyBjJ71fucZuvpiLsdfsfsdfsdfd
...
hoFWWJt3/SeBKn+ci03RRvZsdfdsfsdfw=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFFjCCAv6gAwIBAgIRAJErCErPDBinsdfsfsdfsdfdsfsdfsd
....
nLRbwHqsdqD7hHwg==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFYDCCBsdfSDFSDFVSDVzfsdffvqdsfgsT664ScbvsfGDGSDV
...
Dfvp7OOGAN6dEOM4+SDFSDZET+DFGDFQSD45Bddfghqsqf6Bsff
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

The order must be backwards. The sender's certificate must come first in the list. Each following certificate must directly certify the one preceding it :

`Original issuer —> Intermediate issuer 1 —> Final Root issuer` which is a root certificate authority and can be trusted.

It's possible to have several intermediates : `...—> Intermediate issuer 1 —> Intermediate issuer 2 —>...`

Comment: And what is the order?